# compute elapsed time between rows

Tags: elapsedtime

```
 |   uploadedby   |     uploaddate     |
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-20 20:16:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-20 20:25:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-20 20:35:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-20 20:39:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-20 22:07:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-21 00:04:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-21 01:14:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 17:56:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 18:06:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 18:21:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 19:04:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 19:11:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 19:24:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 20:08:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 20:22:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 21:00:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 22:04:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 22:17:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 22:29:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 23:02:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-23 23:48:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 00:23:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 01:54:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 17:13:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 17:32:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 17:38:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 17:45:00
    Gracey Vinas  | 2012-04-24 17:54:00
```

How do I get the average elapsed time for each upload by date in msql. Ex.(the Average elapsed time for each upload on 2012-04-20 is (time diff of row 1 and row 2(9mins) + time diff of row 2 and row 3(10 mins)  + time difference of row 3 and row 4(4 mins) + time difference for row 4 and row 5(92 mins)/4 = Average elapsed time is 28.75 mins.

Comment: There is an error in your calculation in the example diff between times in row4 and row5 is 88 minutes and not 92, also if you want to get more views you should add some tags, i.e. python

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language so there is a python solution:

```
from re import search
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime

elapsed = []
averages = []
with open("log.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        date = search("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}",line)
        time = search("\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}",line)
        if (date and time):
            elapsed.append((date.group(),datetime.strptime(time.group(),'%H:%M:%S')))
    for date,times in groupby(elapsed,itemgetter(0)):
        times = list(times)
        averages.append((date,(times[-1][1]-times[0][1]).seconds/60./(len(times)-1)))

for avg in averages:
    print 'On date %s average minutes downloading is %.2f' % avg
```

The output for your data in `log.txt` file is:

```
On date 2012-04-20 average minutes downloading is 27.75
On date 2012-04-21 average minutes downloading is 70.00
On date 2012-04-23 average minutes downloading is 27.08
On date 2012-04-24 average minutes downloading is 175.17
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using mysql.